# pandas getting boolean values for a new column in terms of existing columns for each row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to get boolean values for a new column based on existing columns for each row, a sample `dataframe` is,

```
key    doc_no_list    amount    date          doc_no
a1     [1,2]          1.0       2017-10-01    1
a2     [2,1]          1.0       2017-10-01    2
a3     [3]            2.0       2017-10-02    3
a4     [4,5]          3.0       2017-10-03    4
a5     [5,4]          3.0       2017-10-04    5
a6     [2,6]          4.0       2017-10-05    2
a7     [6,2]          4.0       2017-10-05    6
```

for rows with keys `a1` and `a2`, their `doc_no` (not unique) are put in a list `[1,2]` or `[2,1]` (this list has been keeping unique, i.e. no duplicate `doc_no`), since they have the same `amount` value.

Now, for `doc_no_list` values whose sizes > 1, I want to check if the rows corresponding to each `doc_no` in each `doc_no_list` have the same `date` and `amount` values, if they do, put `True` in a new column `same_date`. So a result `dataframe` should look like,

```
key    doc_no_list    amount    date          doc_no    same_date
a1     [1,2]          1.0       2017-10-01    1         True
a2     [2,1]          1.0       2017-10-01    2         True
a3     [3]            2.0       2017-10-02    3         nan
a4     [4,5]          3.0       2017-10-03    4         False
a5     [5,4]          3.0       2017-10-04    5         False
a6     [2,6]          4.0       2017-10-05    2         True
a7     [6,2]          4.0       2017-10-05    6         True
```

I am wondering whats the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than having a column which contains lists I would prefer to have an id for that "doc group":

```
In [11]: df["doc_group"] = df.doc_no_list.apply(lambda ls: hash(tuple(sorted(ls))))

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
  key doc_no_list  amount        date  doc_no            doc_group
0  a1      [1, 2]     1.0  2017-10-01       1  3713081631934410656
1  a2      [2, 1]     1.0  2017-10-01       2  3713081631934410656
2  a3         [3]     2.0  2017-10-02       3        3430021387564
3  a4      [4, 5]     3.0  2017-10-03       4  3713084879518070856
4  a5      [5, 4]     3.0  2017-10-04       5  3713084879518070856
5  a6      [2, 6]     4.0  2017-10-05       2  3713082714458328131
6  a7      [6, 2]     4.0  2017-10-05       6  3713082714458328131
```

*Note: you might be able to do this before without the hash.tuple.sorted e.g. if you have your own id!*

Now you can use the machinery of groupby:

```
In [13]: df.groupby("doc_group")["date"].transform(lambda x: len(x.unique()) == 1)
Out[13]:
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
Name: date, dtype: bool

In [14]: df["same_date"] = df.groupby("doc_group")["date"].transform(lambda x: len(x.unique()) == 1)
```

Comment: You can put the NaN in there too, using `len(x) > 1 && len(x.unique()) == 1`... not sure whether that's too important.

Answer (score 1):

Sort doc_no_list, and join them into one str , then sort it and apply `duplicated`

```
df['same_date']=df.groupby(df['doc_no_list'].apply(sorted).apply(lambda x : ''.join(str(x)))).apply(lambda x : x.duplicated(['amount','date'],keep=False)).reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
df
Out[1246]: 
  key doc_no_list  amount       date  doc_no  same_date
0  a1      [1, 2]       1  10/1/2017       1       True
1  a2      [2, 1]       1  10/1/2017       2       True
2  a3         [3]       2  10/2/2017       3      False
3  a4      [4, 5]       3  10/3/2017       4      False
4  a5      [5, 4]       3  10/4/2017       5      False
5  a6      [2, 6]       4  10/5/2017       2       True
6  a7      [6, 2]       4  10/5/2017       6       True
```